# How to assign Picker and property

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I have ListView (on the MainPage) which lists exercises, and ExercisePage to edit existing or add new items. It works. The problem is how to use picker control to select MuscleGroup on ExercisePage (instead of muscleGroupEntry) with saving changes in Exercise instance?

I tried to use ItemsSource and ItemDisplayBinding properties as described here [Bindable picker](https://codemilltech.com/xamarin-forms-bindable-picker/) but it doesn't work.

Thanks for any help! Here is my code.

Exercise class:

```
    public class Exercise : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public enum muscleGroups
    {
        Back,
        Chest
    }

    public string title { get; set; }
    public muscleGroups muscleGroup { get; set; }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set
        {
            if (title != value)
            {
                title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }
    }

    public muscleGroups MuscleGroup
    {
        get { return muscleGroup; }
        set
        {
            if (muscleGroup != value)
            {
                muscleGroup = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MuscleGroup");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

}
```

ExercisePage.xaml

```
        <StackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="titleEntry" Text="{Binding Path=Title}"  />
        <Entry x:Name="muscleGroupEntry" Text="{Binding Path=MuscleGroup}" />
        <Button Text="Save" Clicked="SaveExercise" />
    </StackLayout>
```

ExercisePage.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class ExercisePage : ContentPage
{
    bool edited = true;
    public Exercise Exercise { get; set; }

    public ExercisePage (Exercise exercise)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        Exercise = exercise;
        if (exercise == null)
        {
            Exercise = new Exercise();
            edited = false;
        }
        this.BindingContext = Exercise;
    }

    async void SaveExercise(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PopAsync();

        if (edited == false)
        {
            NavigationPage navPage = (NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage;
            IReadOnlyList<Page> navStack = navPage.Navigation.NavigationStack;
            MainPage homePage = navStack[navPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1] as MainPage;

            if (homePage != null)
            {
                homePage.AddExercise(Exercise);
            }
        }
    }
```

MainPage.xaml

```
    <StackLayout>
    <Button Text="Add" Clicked="AddButton_Click" />
    <ListView x:Name="exercisesList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemSelected="OnListViewItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Column="0" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding MuscleGroup}" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Column="1" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    protected internal ObservableCollection<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Exercises = new ObservableCollection<Exercise>
        {
            new Exercise {Title="Exercise 1", MuscleGroup = Exercise.muscleGroups.Chest},
            new Exercise {Title="Exercise 2", MuscleGroup = Exercise.muscleGroups.Chest},
            new Exercise {Title="Exercise 3", MuscleGroup = Exercise.muscleGroups.Back},
            new Exercise {Title="Exercise 4", MuscleGroup = Exercise.muscleGroups.Back}
        };
        exercisesList.BindingContext = Exercises;
    }

    private async void OnListViewItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Exercise selectedExercise = args.SelectedItem as Exercise;
        if (selectedExercise != null)
        {
            exercisesList.SelectedItem = null;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ExercisePage(selectedExercise));
        }
    }

    private async void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ExercisePage(null));
    }

    protected internal void AddExercise(Exercise exercise)
    {
        Exercises.Add(exercise);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the code for your Picker?

Comment: I tried this in MainPage.xaml: `<Picker ItemsSource="{x:Static local:Exercises.All}"  
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding MuscleGroup}" />`

Comment: and this code for Exercise class: `static List<Exercise> _allExercises;
    public static List<Exercise> All
    {
        get
        {
            if (_allExercises == null)
            {
                _allExercises = new List<Exercise>
                {
                    new Exercise { Title="Exercise 1", MuscleGroup = Exercise.muscleGroups.Chest},
   ...
                };
            }

            return _allExercises;
        }
    }`

Comment: Jason, I've found another simple desicion:
Add Picker on the ExercisePage

`<Picker x:Name="picker" Title="Choose a muscle group">
     <Picker.Items>
        <x:String>Chest</x:String>
              <x:String>Back</x:String>
         </Picker.Items>
</Picker>`

and (in ExercisePage.xaml.cs) into SaveExercise method add this code:
`switch (picker.SelectedItem)
{
   case "Chest":
      Exercise.MuscleGroup = Exercise.muscleGroups.Chest;
      break;
   case "Back":
      Exercise.MuscleGroup = Exercise.muscleGroups.Back;
      break;
   default:
      break;
}`

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't put a code with new line.

Comment: Please don't add further clarifications as comments, but rather **edit** the question.

Comment: What do you guys think about my way? Can you suggest other ways?